# is there another way to deny access to the settings app apart from hiding it?

Tags: odoo-16

if you assign a user, access to the setting app then you deny them again odoo, seems to be displaying the setting module despite revoking the user access to it.

I have found the problem to be specific to settings module but all the other application seem to obey the rules

I have checked the res.groups table for the settings group and queried the res_groups_users_rel to see if the user still has access to the app but its gone.
Odoo seems not to update it or something on the web view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

odoo has a group *Administration/settings* and a group *Administration/Access Rights*. The two groups are actually defined in the base module in odoo and it took me sometime to figure it out since the category_id are actually set *base/data/ir_module_category_data.xml*.

My issue was I was removing a user from the *Administration/settings* but actually the user was a member of *Administration/Access Rights*, which gave access to the settings menu.